# Why is calculate() in the constructor executed?

Tags: java

in summary

```
WeatherCalculator calculator = WeatherCalculatorFactory.getInstance(Mode.valueOf(mode));

if(mode==Mode.DEW_POINT)
        {
            return new DewPointCalculator();
        }

public class DewPointCalculator extends WeatherCalculator{
    //default constructor
    public DewPointCalculator()
    {
        this(null);
    }

    public WeatherCalculator(WeatherData weatherData) { 
        this.weatherData = weatherData; 
        calculate(); //calculate overriding
    }
    public WeatherCalculator()
    {
        this(null);
    }
```

The line breaks are all different classes.
I wonder why calculate() in the constructor is executed when no object has been passed here.

Comment: As a summary, the compiler will not work.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You do call the first constructor with `this(null)`. To call the second, no-argument constructor you can use `this()`.
However, the second constructor still calls `this(null)` so the first constructor will be called either way.

The thing about null is that *null can be anything, and anything can be null*.
So by calling `this(null)` you *are* passing a WeatherData, it is just null (and using it would result in an error).

Answer (score 1):

You are overloading constructors in class **WeatherCalculator** this is known as **`Explicit Constructor Invocation`**

You have two constructors in the class WeatherCalculator

1. WeatherCalculator() //Non parameterized constructor
2. WeatherCalculator(WeatherData weatherData) //parameterized constructor

what happens when you create an object of the WeatherCalculator class the WeatherCalculator() constructor is called which calls **this(null)** the parameterized constructor(WeatherCalculator(WeatherData weatherData)) and the calculate method is executed.